# How does G Suite detect SCIM support?

Tags: google-workspace, scim

I'm trying to setup user provisioning in G Suite for my SCIM-implementing application. According to [the documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7000629?hl=en), it should be a relatively straightforward task: make sure G Suite knows about `/auth` and `/scim` endpoints, and you're done.

But the point is, the very option of 'User Provisioning' in my application is not active (not visible, to be precise). Again, quoting the docs:

> Select the user provisioning section. You will only see this choice if
>   your application uses the System for Cross-domain Identity Management
>   (SCIM) specification.

The question is, how exactly the system understands that without knowing the 'root' SCIM endpoint? Does the spec dictate some common endpoint for SCIM service discovery - for example, should the server always respond to `'/ServiceProviderConfig'` (and not `'/scim/v2/ServiceProviderConfig'`, for example?)

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm interested as well.

This is how Keeper does it: https://docs.keeper.io/sso-connect-guide/identity-provider-setup/g-suite-configuration

Answer (score 5):

From talking with the GSuite support team a few times over the last 18 months I believe this is only possible with apps in their "catalog".

See the following at the header of the page "[Configure automated user provisioning for your app](https://support.google.com/a/topic/6400789?hl=en&visit_id=637484046046142699-1751393377&rd=1)"

> After you set up SSO for an app in our SAML catalog, follow steps here to configure automated user provisioning for your app.

I was given [this link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQZYsNg2uu_PZYFeSKudkT6fV1PoMPylTfnHK6PWVYrdMtNQ/viewform) as the place to go to begin the process of registering an app, but having never received a response I was informed the team has not been accepting new submissions since October 2019.

I'd be very glad to hear more positive news on this if anyone's got any!!